# Ubuntu File Manager Actions

Tags: files

### Context Menu Manager

Is there such thing for Ubuntu 20?

I would like to add custom context menu entry, like "new gedit file" on a context menu of file manager of gnome shell.

Answer (score 0):

To add a right-click menu entry for a template file, create that file in an editor, like gedit, give it a name of your choice, like "new gedit file", move it to the "Templates" folder in your user's home directory. Now it will be available under "New Document" sub-menu when you right-click in an empty space in a directory in GNOME Files. That sub-menu shows up only if the "Templates" folder is not empty. Works on a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [Nautilus Actions](https://installati.one/ubuntu/20.04/nautilus-actions/) or [FileManager-Actions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/filemanager-actions).

`filemanager-actions` can be used to create a new entry in the file manager context menu. I was able to use it to create a "Refresh" option in the right click context menu.

You should be able to create an action to create a new file!

I would direct you to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138682/1569605) by Norbert for details on how to make it work.

As for Nautilus Actions

> Nautilus actions is an extension for Nautilus, the GNOME file manager. It allows the configuration of programs to be launched on files selected in the Nautilus interface. . The project has undergone a name change since other GNOME-based file managers, like Caja and Nemo, are now supported as well. This package provides an easy way to upgrade to FileManager-Actions. It can be safely removed.

Since Ubuntu 19.04, Nautilus Actions is a transitory package for FileManager-Actions which is the now supported program (unsure of their exact relation)